# app not build for Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: android, cordova, build

```
 I cannot build the app after i installed cordova plugin. Getting the following error
```

"Execution failed for task ':compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.".
I installed Android Studio version 4.2.1 on Windows 10. My Gradle doesn't build after trying for around 2 days. I have a problem that I don't understand.

i tried platfrom remove and add again but get same error,also change ionic version but not resolve this issue

````
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    apply from: 'repositories.gradle'
    repositories repos

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    apply from: 'repositories.gradle'
    repositories repos

    //This replaces project.properties w.r.t. build settings
    project.ext {
      defaultBuildToolsVersion="29.0.2" //String
      defaultMinSdkVersion=22 //Integer - Minimum requirement is Android 5.1
      defaultTargetSdkVersion=29 //Integer - We ALWAYS target the latest by default
      defaultCompileSdkVersion=29 //Integer - We ALWAYS compile with the latest by default
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)             : 4.3.0 (C:\Users\MS\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.5.3
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.1000.8
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 10.0.8
   @angular/cli                  : 10.0.8
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.3.3

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 10.0.0
   Cordova Platforms     : 6.0.0, android 9.1.0, browser
   Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.2.1, (and 14 other plugins)

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (C:\Users\MS\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk)
   NodeJS            : v14.17.1 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm               : 7.18.1
   OS                : Windows 10```
````

Answer (score 0):

Add below line in your gradle.property and run again

```
org.gradle.java.home=/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home
```